# how can pass the src of an in an array of object through a props to another components,Can someone explain to me why I can't show my Images

Tags: reactjs, image

```js
import React from 'react';
import Gallery from '../Gallery/Gallery';

const Galleries = (props) => {
  const galleries = [
    {
      name: 'natur',
      src: ' ../../Images/photographer-gfc1c015b1_1920.jpg',
    },

    {
      name: 'moutain',
      src: ' ../../Images/photographer-gfc1c015b1_1920.jpg',
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {/* generate the numbre of data */}
      <h1>I have {galleries.length} Images</h1>

      {galleries.map((gallery) => (
        <Gallery name={gallery.name} galery={gallery.src} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Galleries;

import React from 'react';

const Gallery = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <img src={props.src} alt="" style={{ height: '200px', width: '300px' }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer but it's not working either

Comment: when I inspect in the elements I see onmy this :   <img alt="" style="height: 200px; width: 300px;">.                                                                                                                                                  So my SRC does not work

Answer (score 0):

here is your mistake, wrong props are getting used,
you are passing this `<Gallery name={gallery.name} galery={gallery.src} />`

change this line, this is wrong line, using `src`, but you never passed src,

```
<img src={props.src} alt="" style={{ height: '200px', width: '300px' }} />
```

change to this, this will work fine, `props.galery` works

```
<img src={props.galery} alt="" style={{ height: '200px', width: '300px' }} />
```